# Dense final layer vs. another rnn layer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

It is common to add a dense fully-connected layer as the last layer on top of a recurrent neural network (which has one or more layers) in order to learn the reduction to the final output dimensionality.

Let's say I need one output with a -1 to 1 range, in which case I would use a dense layer with a tanh activation function.

My question is: Why not add another recurrent layer instead with an internal size of 1?

It will be different (in the sense of propagating that through time) but will it have a disadvantage over the dense layer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the two alternatives you present do the exact same computation, so they should behave identically.

In TensorFlow, if you're using `dynamic_rnn`, it's much easier if all time steps are identical, though, hence processing the output instead of having a different last step.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain clearly. This is not related to time step size. The dense layer's input is a single RNN's output (which is the cell's num_units in tensorflow's notation). And they wouldn't be identical because the dense layer does not get any information propagated through time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand still... are you talking about layers within the rnn_cell?

Comment: No. I'm talking about the state size. For example 512 in `lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units = 512)`. The number of layers is irrelevant (the question applies to any number of layers). If I want a single output in the range [-1,1], I could put a dense layer with 512 inputs and a tanh activation function. Or I could stack another LSTM layer with state size of 1. What are the pros and cons?

Comment: If you stack another LSTM you will get temporal interactions in that layer as well, while a dense layer will ignore it (but will also do less compute). Whether either is better will depend on your data, I think.